# Duda función Js con Session Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, lista

Tengo un botón que manda un elemento de una tabla al portapapeles. Sin embargo, cuando selecciono varios elementos, solamente me llega a mandar uno en lugar de varios.

Este es el código: (Row Selected sería el elemento seleccionado)

```
$('#buttonsDocumentacion .botonClipboard').on('click', function(){
        clipboard = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("clipboard"));
        if($.inArray(rowSelected[0], clipboard) < 0){
            if(clipboard == null){
                clipboard = [];
            }
            clipboard.push(rowSelected[0]);
            sessionStorage.setItem('clipboard', JSON.stringify(clipboard));
        }
        compruebaClipboard();
    });
```

**rowSeleted[0]** no es el primero de la lista, sino que el id de dicho elemento.

Con **clipboard.push(...rowSelected)** no es lo que quiero, ya que manda la carpeta padre y el elemento seleccionado.

---

Tengo otra alternativa como:

```
$('#buttonsDocumentation .botonClipboard').on('click', function(){
    var idsClip=[];
    if(clipboard = tableDocs.rows('.selected').data()){
        for(var i=0; i<clipboard.length; i++){
            idsClip.push(clipboard[i][0]);
        }   
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem('clipboard', JSON.stringify(idsClip));
    testClipboard();
});
```

Esto me funciona porque hace el envío al portapapeles, pero tengo otra tabla (tableSearch) que comparte la misma botonera y esa no funciona. Si pongo || o && no funciona y me coge la primera.

Comment: Como estás haciendo la selección de los elementos?, Ej: checkbox, select, radio..

Comment: @LuisS.Romero seleccionado la fila de una tabla, referenciando a rowSelected, no es checkbox, ni radio.

Comment: ¿No deberías añadir todos los elementos selecionados? algo como `clipboard.push(...rowSelected)` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Java != JavaScript. Por favor no añadas etiquetas que no tienen nada que ver

Comment: @PabloLozano nada, gracias por la documentación pero no me sirve.

Comment: utilizas algun framework para la tabla?

Comment: Dices que rowSelected[0] es el elemento seleccionado. Por tanto, este código mete UN elemento en el array clipboard. ¿Donde están el resto de elementos seleccionados?

Answer (score 0):

Armé este ejemplo con javascript-data-grid, documentación de selection: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-selection/
Por cada click llama a la funciónonSelectionChanged, la cual sencillamente devuelve un console.log con un array de objetos, cada objeto es una de las row seleccionadas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.noStyle.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container pt-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div
        id="myGrid"
        class="ag-theme-alpine"
        style="height: 450px; width: 650px"
      ></div>
    </div>

<!-- ------------- Empieza El SCRIPT ------------- -->

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     
 // specify the columns
      const columnDefs = [
        { field: "make" },
        { field: "model" },
        { field: "price" },
      ];

      // specify the data
      const rowData = [
        { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
        { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
        { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 },
        { make: "Fiat", model: "Uno", price: 5000 },
        { make: "Chevrolet", model: "Spark", price: 3000 },
        { make: "Suzuki", model: "SPreso", price: 7000 },
      ];

      // let the grid know which columns and what data to use
      const gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        rowSelection: "multiple",
        rowData: rowData,
        onSelectionChanged: onSelectionChanged,
      };

      // lookup the container we want the Grid to use
      const eGridDiv = document.querySelector("#myGrid");

      // create the grid passing in the div to use together with the columns & data we want to use
      new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);

    function onSelectionChanged() {
      let selectedRows = gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
      console.log(selectedRows);
  }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta ... al final he tirado por otra alternativa que la contesto abajo de esta pero tengo un problema que no sé solventarlo al ser dos tablas que comparten el mismo botón